# how to handle the responseString from json output and parse it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I am using the following code and i am getting a response string in JSON. I don't know how to parse it. What should I do next if I want to call any method on JSON output

// source code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDzl0Ozijg2C47iYfKgBWWkAbZE_wCJ-2U&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures&callback=handleResponse"]]retain];    

    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [myConnection start];    
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    [dataWebService setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [dataWebService appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);

    [responseString release];
    [dataWebService release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error during connection: %@", [error description]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JSON parsing framework: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Comment: thank u for ur response i am getting output but how to parse as tutorial provided in below website   http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/76730-webservice-how.html

Comment: Yeah, just like that: NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];   Doesn't get much easier

Comment: in which method i shd call NSDictionary *dictionary? i am new to iphone i dont know much coding..

Comment: In replace of: NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);